KDE Plasma with x11 sometimes doesn't load?
After I boot my PC (Tuxedo OS 22.04) sometimes KDE Plasma (6.1.2) won't load anything at the Desktop, only wallpaper and widgets. No menu bar, no icons. And also GPU (Nvidia RTX 3050Ti) is running at around 30% when this happens, and I'm not sure why. No logs in dmesg, nothing. I have to press ctrl + alt + t to open terminal and reboot the PC, because nothing works.
What could cause this and where should I search for solution/logs?
GPU drivers are 550.90.07.
I think this troubles started to happen after I updated to Plasma 6 when Tuxedo distributed the packages.

I have a wayland installed by default as second display server, but I'm not using it at all, it flickers, and stuffs.

